# I'm trying to use gpg2 with a pypass password store and am missing a file. How do I point the python program to .gpg-id?

Tags: python, gnupg

I'm getting the error message when trying to use pypass,  a very intuitive password manager.
with the command

````
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line
26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypass/command.py", line 56, in main
    'password_store': PasswordStore(
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypass/passwordstore.py", line 64, in __init__
    raise Exception("could not find .gpg-id file")
Exception: could not find .gpg-id file```

How do I point python to a .gpg-id file? Does it need strict permissions?  Does gpg2 generate it?
Thank you in advance.
````

Comment: any command i put in.  e.g. ``` pi@hostname$ pypass show```

Answer (score 0):

It Doesn't need any permission just put your gpg encrypted files in `~/.password-store` pypass looks for gpg files in this directory and I hope you have installed all the requirements like `gnupg` and `tree` if not you can do so using this command `sudo apt-get install -y gnupg tree`. If you just want to test the APIs you can download an example gpg key provided by pypass using this command `gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import pypass/tests/test_key_sec.asc` and you need to trust this key `gpg --import-ownertrust pypass/tests/test_ownertrust.txt` for further information please refer to the documentation [here](https://pypass.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) and [here](https://www.passwordstore.org/)